# Friendly url's not showing up in search results (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, friendly-url, sharepoint-search

We have build an internet website (anonymous access) with some customizations (masterpage/ styling, etc.). For navigation we've used managed navigation, driven by the termstore.

**Our problem is that we are not seeing any friendly url in the search results(except for 3)**

I have done numerous checks: Friendly url's are working fine for anonymous users. Navigation works okay. I have logged in with the crawler account to check for security issues etc. I have checked the crawl log, besides 3 friendly urls, all other friendly urlsare missing. Note that the physical url's are showing up just fine.I also checked the standard SharePoint logfilesto check for warnings etc. during crawling.Also I've looked into the result sources, but no lock there.

I also played with the page setting 'Hide physical path from search results' (this is checked by default when you create a friendly urlfor a page).I also reset all masterpagesto both Seattle.masterand Oslo.master(note that I believe the latter one is more suitable for anonymous sites)torule out masterpage/ html customizations (e.g. noindexattribute etc.).

Any suggestions? I believe this should work 'out of the box' and we cannot find any other people having this issue (it's happening on all our environments!).

Thanks in advance!

Best regards, Wilko

Comment: We have the same problem here. Did anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

We have perhaps a very similar issue, which we narrowed down to the site template "BLANKINTERNET". Site Content Page (say /pages/pageone.aspx) is crawled, friendly url (say /servername/pageone) was not. Try with a team site and see if that works for you.